# UnderscoreJS -- _.some() vs _.find()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

From what I've read in the documentation, _.find() functions very similarly to _.some()

Does anyone know whether there are (performance) advantages between the two?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Their performance characteristics are probably the same, assuming you want to know wether to use [`find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) or [`some`](http://underscorejs.org/#some) in a specific case. They are both lazy in the same way.

The difference is in the output. `find` will return the value, `some` will return a `boolean`.

---

I checked the source (1.4.4). `some` and `find` both use `some` (=== `any`) internally. So even if a native implementation of `some` is used it benefits both `find` and `some`.

Comment: Another subtle difference is that `some` will use a native implementation if available, I'm not sure the same is true for `find`

Answer (score 4):

If you look into it's source, you will find that those two are identical, _.find actually calls _.some.

```
_.find = _.detect = function(obj, iterator, context) {
  var result;
  any(obj, function(value, index, list) {
    if (iterator.call(context, value, index, list)) {
      result = value;
      return true;
    }
  });
  return result;
};

var any = _.some = _.any = function(obj, iterator, context) {
  iterator || (iterator = _.identity);
  var result = false;
  if (obj == null) return result;
  if (nativeSome && obj.some === nativeSome) return obj.some(iterator, context);
  each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
    if (result || (result = iterator.call(context, value, index, list))) return breaker;
  });
  return !!result;
};
```